# django: how do i make tables out of two for loops?

Tags: django

I have two columns (models), `ColumnLeft` and `ColumnRight`. To loop through the models to output the rows in a table I have used the `for` loop. I want to put both Columns in the same table.

```
|--------------------------|
|ColumnLeft  |  ColumnRight|
|--------------------------|
|1           |a            |
|2           |b            |
|3           |c            |
|--------------------------|
```

The html for the table I have made is this.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ColumnLeft</th>
        <th>ColumnRight</th>
    </tr>
    {% for i in left %} 
    <tr>
    {% for f in right %}  
        <td>{{i}}</td>
        <td>{{f}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

This out puts the table like this:

```
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|ColumnLeft  |  ColumnRight|            |             |            |             |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|1           |a            |1           |b            |1           |c            |
|2           |a            |2           |b            |2           |c            |
|3           |a            |3           |b            |3           |c            |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
```

Whats the best why to output the table like in my first example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to zip the columns together in your view:

```
rows = zip(left, right)
```

Now in your template:

```
{% for left, right in rows %} 
  <tr>
    <td>{{ left }}</td>
    <td>{{ right }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```